# I want to Mock a Azure function with ServiceBusTrigger using MsTest with Moq

Tags: c#, azure-functions, moq, mstest, azure-servicebus-topics

I want to Mock a Azure function with ServiceBusTrigger using MsTest with Moq. How do I Mock the below code

```
    [FunctionName("TransformFunction")]
    public async void Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("testmessagetopic", "testMessageSubscription", Connection = "ConnectionString")]Message mySbMsg,
            [ServiceBus("loaddatatopic", Connection = "ConnectionString")]IAsyncCollector<Message> loadDataSbQueue,
            ILogger log)
    {   //Does something         
        await this._cfcExtractorService.ProcessAsync(mySbMsg, loadDataSbQueue);
    }
```

I am new to this AzureFunctions. I would like to know how to mock this.

Answer (score 1):

[`IAsyncCollector`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/IAsyncCollector.cs) is a simple interface which you could simply implement as part of your test library by adding each entry into a list and at the end check if the expected items where added to the list.

[This](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-unittesting-sample/blob/master/DotNet/FunctionTestHelper/FunctionTest.cs#L38) is an implementation you could refer to and here is the same for reference

```cs
public class AsyncCollector<T> : IAsyncCollector<T>
{
    public readonly List<T> Items = new List<T>();

    public Task AddAsync(T item, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {

        Items.Add(item);

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    public Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```